# ¿select que quite o agregue dinero desde un input type="text"?

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito quitar o agregar un monto, según la opción mediante el siguiente selector y muestre el valor elegido al dar click al botón de Aplicar

```html
<div>
    <select id="altaVendedorCategoria" name="altaVendedorCategoria">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Opciones</option>
        <option value="value1">Agregar</option>
        <option value="value2">Quitar</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Ingresa el monto:</p>
    <input type="text" value="0" name="montoMonedero" id="montoMonedero" placeholder="MONTO PARA MONEDERO *" maxlength="3" onKeypress="return soloNumeros(event);" />
</div>
<div style="margin-top:14px">
    <button>Aplicar</button>
</div>
<div  style="margin-top:14px">
    Monto monedero: <b>$</b>
</div>
```

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a SO en español! Léete [ask] y haz el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y realizar buenas preguntas. En tu caso tu pregunta carece de un [example] de lo que has intentado, ni muestras lo que has investigado, ni tampoco das información sobre los errores que has tenido ni donde te has encallado. En resumen, como decimos por aqui, no has hecho nada de lo que pretendes conseguir. Eso puede suponer el cierre de la pregunta y/o votos negativos. Pulsa en [edit] para agregar la información requerida, gracias. **Aqui no hacemos tareas (o no deberiamos), lo siento**

Answer (score 1):

Realice la respuesta, de esta manera ya que la utilice según a mis necesidades, les explico un poco.
Me traigo un resultado de una consulta y lo meto al input="text" y de ese resultado quiero o agregar o quitar dinero a ese monedero y mostrarlo en otro input el resultado ya sea de la suma o de la resta, y este fue el resultado, si funciona solo que cada quien utilizelo a sus necesidades.

```js
    function AgregarQuitarMonedero(e){
   
    var monedero = document.getElementById("monedero").value;
    

    if (monedero == 0 ) {

      var monto1 =  document.getElementById("montoMonedero").value;
      var monto2 =  document.getElementById("totalMontoMonedero").value;

      var suma = (parseInt(monto1) + parseInt(monto2)); 
      
      document.getElementById("actualizarIdMonedero").value = suma;
       

    }else{

      var monto1 =  document.getElementById("montoMonedero").value;
      var monto2 =  document.getElementById("totalMontoMonedero").value;

      var resta = (parseInt(monto2) - parseInt(monto1)); 

      document.getElementById("actualizarIdMonedero").value = resta;
      


    }
```

```html
  <div class="colLg12 colMd12 colSm24 colXs24 paddingOn etiquetasForm">
                <p class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 etiquetaFija centerText">OPCIONES PARA MONEDERO</p>
                <select class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 " id="monedero" name="monedero">
                  <option value="-1" selected>Opciones</option>
                  <option value="0">Agregar</option>
                  <option value="1" >Quitar</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="colLg12 colMd12 colSm24 colXs24 paddingOn etiquetasForm">
                  <p class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 etiquetaFija centerText">MONTO</p>
                  <input type="text"  class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 monto" name="montoMonedero" id="montoMonedero" placeholder="INGRESA EL MONTO" maxlength="5" onKeypress="return soloNumeros(event);" />
                  <input type="hidden"  class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 monto" name="totalMontoMonedero" id="totalMontoMonedero"  />
                  <input type="hidden"  class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 monto" name="resultadoMontoMonedero" id="resultadoMontoMonedero"  />
                  <input type="hidden"  class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24" name="actualizarIdMonedero" id="actualizarIdMonedero"  />
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

lo que tienes que hacer, es que cuando le des al botón, llame a la función:

```
<div>
        <select id="altaVendedorCategoria" name="altaVendedorCategoria">
            <option value="" selected disabled>Opciones</option>
            <option value="agregar">Agregar</option>
            <option value="quitar">Quitar</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Ingresa el monto:</p>
        <input type="number" value="0" name="montoMonedero" id="montoMonedero" placeholder="MONTO PARA MONEDERO *"
            maxlength="3" />
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:14px">
        <button onclick="calcular()">Aplicar</button>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:14px">
        Monto monedero: <input type="number" id="total" readonly value="0"></input><b>$</b>
    </div>

    <script>
        function calcular() {
            var monto = document.getElementById("montoMonedero").value;
            var movimiento = document.getElementById("altaVendedorCategoria").value;
            var antiguo = document.getElementById("total").value;
            var valor = 0;
            monto = parseInt(monto);
            antiguo = parseInt(antiguo);


            if (movimiento != "") {
                if (movimiento == "agregar") {
                    valor = antiguo + monto;
                } else {
                    valor = antiguo - monto;
                }
            }
            
            document.getElementById("total").value = valor;
        }   
    </script>
```

En ésta función, primero vas a sacar los valores: El que pones en el monto, el tipo de movimiento que quieres hacer y el valor antiguo. También utilizarmos una nueva variable donde guardaremos el resultado.

Luego simplemente haces una comprobación de que el tipo de movimiento sea o Agregar o Quitar, y en cada caso haces la ecuación necesaria.

Comment: Muchas gracias te agradezco c:

Comment: Me alegro :) Si te ha servido, estaría bien que pusieses como resuelta, para futuros usuarios.